# importing customers from magento 1 that have more than one address

Tags: magento2, importexport, customer-address

I have around 7000 customers that i exported from magento 1 and now need to import to magento 2.

The customers have more than one address, any idea how i can fix this ?

```
Header contains invalid attribute(s): "website", "billing_prefix", "billing_firstname", "billing_middlename", "billing_lastname", "billing_suffix", "billing_street_full", "billing_city", "billing_region", "billing_country", "billing_postcode", "billing_telephone", "billing_company", "billing_fax", "shipping_prefix", "shipping_firstname", "shipping_middlename", "shipping_lastname", "shipping_suffix", "shipping_street_full", "shipping_city", "shipping_region", "shipping_country", "shipping_postcode", "shipping_telephone", "shipping_company", "shipping_fax", "is_subscribed"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution :

STEP1: import the customers without addresses by creating a " Customers main fail" and respecting its headers.

STEP2: import the customers shipping addresses only by creating an "customer addresses" file, make the _address_default_shipping_ 1 and the _address_default_billing_ 0.

STEP3: import the customers billing addresses only by creating another "customer addresses" file, make the _address_default_shipping_ 0 and the _address_default_billing_ 1.